# Linux find folder inside subfolders

Tags: linux, find

I am trying to find a directory named `480debugerror` nested under child directories. I don't know the exact path, or even if I have the exact spelling of the directory I want to find.

Is there a Linux command to find directories with a given prefix or suffix, for example directories with a name of "debug" or "debug error", with some prefix or suffix that is unknown?

Comment: You can try `locate` (locates files) or `find` (finds files).

Comment: find -type f -name *ummy... but not get

Comment: You need -type *d*. `f` searches for files

Answer (score 26):

[`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) is what you need:

```
$ find -type d -name '*debugerror*'
```

or

```
$ find -type d -name '480debugerror'
```

if you are certain about the folder name.

Answer (score 8):

```
find . -type d \( -iname '*error*' -o -iname '*debug*' \)
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash,

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
echo **/*480*/
echo **/*debug*/
echo **/*error*/
```

searches recursively for directories with names containing 480, debug or error.

Answer (score 1):

```
locate -i "480debugerror"
```

will check a database that lists all the files indexed on your PC. I often have scenarios like this and so I do searches like:

```
locate -i "debug" | grep -i "log"
```

which finds all files that have in their path (regardless of case [that's what -i means]) "debug" and "log" (In case you don't know, the `| grep` means search within the results that locate produces)

The advantage to using locate over find is that locate will produce output much faster (since it's only checking a database) but if the file/folder is not indexed then it will not find anything. (to update the database you can use `sudo updatedb`)

Comment: Only if you have `slocate` installed. Some production environment does not :-(

Comment: True but if an option I would say it's superior to find...